# How to embed MongoDB charts into application

Tags: mongodb, charts

I created charts in MongoDB Charts, but do not know how to use those charts in my web application. Are there ways to publish MongoDB charts to a link where everyone can access without logging in?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Are there ways to publish MongoDB charts to a link where everyone can access without logging in?

In [MongoDB Charts](https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/master/) version 0.10 , there is no way to publish charts into external web site/application.

In regards to permissions, that would include setting `read` role on the chart's data sources for everyone too. See also [Charts Dashboard Permissions](https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/master/dashboard-permissions/)

**UPDATE:**

Now you can use the Embedding feature to render the charts in an external web application. When you embed a chart, you can choose whether you want it to be `Unauthenticated` (meaning anyone who has the embed code can view the chart), or to use `Verified Signature` authentication (which checks the integrity of a signature in the URL before the chart will render). See [Charts Embedding Examples](https://github.com/mongodb/charts-embedding-examples) for more information.

Comment: Is there anyway we can change the styling of the charts

Comment: You can customise high-level aspects of the charts such as colours and data labels. See also https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/saas/customize-charts

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. Can I somehow change the font style?